# IText - Edit Spanish Document Using PdfDictionary and PDF Stamper

Tags: java, pdf, character-encoding, itext, character-set

I am trying to read a document using itext and replace a string in it. But once manipulated all spanish character becomes junk characters. Below is the code for changing the pdf.

```
    PdfReader     reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary dict   = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfObject     object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    if (object instanceof PRStream) {
        PRStream stream     = (PRStream) object;
        byte[]   data       = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
        String   dataString = new String(data);
        dataString = dataString.replace(sourceString, replacementString);
        stream.setData(dataString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

In the actual pdf there is a string ${address-line-one} which I am replacing to "20th Street"

This works but with this Spanish word which is in the stream

Documentación becomes Documentaciï¿½n

and same for other spanish word.

I also printed the bytes[] in java console, and found that the reading itself doesn't get that character properly.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
new String(data)
```

to turn the bytes into a string (using some default encoding) and

```
dataString.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

to turn the string back into bytes (using utf-8).

Thus, if the default encoding in the first operation does not match utf-8, these transformations will create artefacts as you see above.

So please use

```
new String(data, encoding)
```

and

```
dataString.getBytes(encoding)
```

instead.

---

That been said, utf-8 is a very inappropriate encoding here,  use something along the lines of Latin-1 / ISO-8559-1 instead.

---

That been said your approach at editing the content will only work in very specific PDFs. In particular the encodings of the used fonts must be **WinAnsiEncoding** and lines or "fields" must be drawn in a single instruction each. Furthermore, your replacements must not be much longer than the replaced text and must not contain characters for which Latin-1 and  WinAnsiEncoding differ or which have special meanings in PDFs, and you must make sure that you do not by chance change the instructions outside the strings.

Comment: Can't do ++1 as my reputation is not that high, but this worked for me:::


String   dataString = new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");dataString = dataString.replace(sourceString, replacementString);stream.setData(dataString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

Comment: Good. Beware of the warnings further down, though: If the producer of your PDFs will ever change, your code suddenly might stop working. By the way, you indeed cannot *upvote* but you can *accept* an answer, simply click the tick at its upper left, right below the voting arrows.

Comment: I myself is creating the pdf from IText and than changing text some where down the line, so I am the producer and consumer in this case :) thanks though